# Repeated unequal measures 3-way ANOVA in r

Tags: r, anova

I'm a new user of the R. I'm trying to analyze my data with 3 way ANOVA. The data below contains 3 factors, and factor of time is repeatedly measured. There are 4 groups, but the sample sizes are different.

| id | sex | exercises | t1 | t2 | t3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | V | 0.9 | 1.1 | 1.1 |
| 2 | M | V | 0.9 | 1.1 | 1.2 |
| 3 | M | V | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 4 | M | V | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.8 |
| 5 | M | V | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 6 | M | V | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 8 | F | V | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 9 | F | V | 0.9 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | F | V | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 11 | F | V | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 12 | F | V | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.8 |
| 13 | M | P | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.8 |
| 14 | M | P | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 26 | M | P | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.9 |
| 15 | M | P | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.8 |
| 16 | M | P | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.8 |
| 17 | M | P | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.8 |
| 18 | M | P | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.8 |
| 19 | M | P | 0.9 | 0.7 | 0.8 |
| 20 | F | P | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 21 | F | P | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.8 |
| 22 | F | P | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.9 |
| 23 | F | P | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 24 | F | P | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 25 | F | P | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.8 |

I tried one of the online tutorials for 3 way ANOVA ([https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/repeated-measures-anova-in-r/#three-way](https://stackoverflow.com)) and the errors showed when I used this code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(readxl)
setwd("my dir here")
weightloss <- read_xlsx("test.xlsx")
weightloss <- weightloss %>%
gather(key = "time", value = "score", t1, t2, t3) %>%
convert_as_factor(id, sex, exercises, time)
res.aov <- anova_test(
  data = weightloss, dv = score, wid = id,
  within = c(sex, exercises, time)
  )
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

Here's the error information:

**Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
0 (non-NA) cases**

I guess the tutorial is for data with the same sample sizes. Can I modify this code or is there a better code for 3 way ANOVA? Thanks!

Edit(07/27/23) I added `print(weightloss)` and `dput(weightloss)` results below:

```
weightloss %>% print(n=100)
       id    sex   exercises time  score
    <fct> <fct> <fct>     <fct> <dbl>
    1 1     M     V         t1      0.9
    2 2     M     V         t1      0.9
    3 3     M     V         t1      0.8
    4 4     M     V         t1      0.8
    5 5     M     V         t1      0.9
    6 6     M     V         t1      0.8
    7 8     F     V         t1      0.9
    8 9     F     V         t1      0.9
    9 10    F     V         t1      0.9
    10 11    F     V         t1      0.9
    11 12    F     V         t1      0.9
    12 13    M     P         t1      0.9
    13 14    M     P         t1      0.9
    14 26    M     P         t1      0.9
    15 15    M     P         t1      0.9
    16 16    M     P         t1      0.9
    17 17    M     P         t1      0.9
    18 18    M     P         t1      0.9
    19 19    M     P         t1      0.9
    20 20    F     P         t1      0.9
    21 21    F     P         t1      0.9
    22 22    F     P         t1      0.9
    23 23    F     P         t1      0.9
    24 24    F     P         t1      0.9
    25 25    F     P         t1      0.9
    26 1     M     V         t2      1.1
    27 2     M     V         t2      1.1
    28 3     M     V         t2      0.9
    29 4     M     V         t2      0.9
    30 5     M     V         t2      0.9
    31 6     M     V         t2      0.9
    32 8     F     V         t2      0.9
    33 9     F     V         t2      1  
    34 10    F     V         t2      0.9
    35 11    F     V         t2      0.9
    36 12    F     V         t2      0.9
    37 13    M     P         t2      0.8
    38 14    M     P         t2      0.9
    39 26    M     P         t2      0.8
    40 15    M     P         t2      0.8
    41 16    M     P         t2      0.8
    42 17    M     P         t2      0.8
    43 18    M     P         t2      0.8
    44 19    M     P         t2      0.7
    45 20    F     P         t2      0.9
    46 21    F     P         t2      0.9
    47 22    F     P         t2      0.8
    48 23    F     P         t2      0.9
    49 24    F     P         t2      0.9
    50 25    F     P         t2      0.8
    51 1     M     V         t3      1.1
    52 2     M     V         t3      1.2
    53 3     M     V         t3      0.9
    54 4     M     V         t3      0.8
    55 5     M     V         t3      0.9
    56 6     M     V         t3      0.9
    57 8     F     V         t3      0.9
    58 9     F     V         t3      1  
    59 10    F     V         t3      0.9
    60 11    F     V         t3      0.9
    61 12    F     V         t3      0.8
    62 13    M     P         t3      0.8
    63 14    M     P         t3      0.9
    64 26    M     P         t3      0.9
    65 15    M     P         t3      0.8
    66 16    M     P         t3      0.8
    67 17    M     P         t3      0.8
    68 18    M     P         t3      0.8
    69 19    M     P         t3      0.8
    70 20    F     P         t3      0.9
    71 21    F     P         t3      0.8
    72 22    F     P         t3      0.9
    73 23    F     P         t3      0.9
    74 24    F     P         t3      0.9
    75 25    F     P         t3      0.8
```

```
dput(weightloss)
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 25L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 25L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 25L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L
), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "24", "25", "26"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    exercises = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("P", "V"), class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("t1", "t2", "t3"), class = "factor"), 
    score = c(0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
    0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
    0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.1, 1.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 0.9, 
    0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 
    0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 1.1, 1.2, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 
    0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 
    0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8)), row.names = c(NA, -75L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What are the errors you get? Please copy and paste them into the question so we know what happened

Comment: @divibisan
Hi, I edited and added the error information. Thanks.

Comment: The error message suggests a problem with your data, not your code.  What does `print(weightloss)` give you?  Please add the output of `dput(weightloss)` to your question.  That will tell us what you *actually* have, not what you *think* you have.

Comment: It seems that the `anova_test` only does a 2 way anova. It is documented anywhere to do a 3 way anova?

Comment: @Limey I agree. I checked the ```print(weightloss)``` results and it seems to be what I need. I added the results here.

Comment: @Onyambu, Yes, here's the link says it can do 3 way ANOVA (https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/repeated-measures-anova-in-r/#three-way). You know, I'm a new user of the R so I could just learn from the tutorials.